# how do I use the grep command to match a particular pattern ? if pattern specified in grep is "4" it should not return lines containing 44

Tags: shell, grep

When i use the grep command as follows :

```
rollno=4
grep $rollno=4 new.txt
```

it returns the records that contain 44 or 4444 or 24,etc as roll no.How do i eliminate this flaw?

Comment: your command will expand to `grep 4=4 new.txt`. Is it what you want?

Comment: could you please explain in more details what your are trying to achieve? basically your pattern `4` matches all lines that at least contains character `4`, no matter of rest

Comment: What a weird migration!

Answer (score 4):

If you have GNU `grep`, then `grep -w 4` will look for 'words' that consist of the digit 4 alone.

```
grep -w 4 <<eof
This line contains 4 all alone.
This line doesn't because of this 44.
This line contains '4' all alone too.
This line does not because 4x4 looks like a word.
eof
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains one record per line, you can use

```
grep -E "^4$"
```

The `-E` option tells `grep` to accept regular expressions, and in the expression `^` stands for "beginning of line" and `$` stands for "end of line".

Answer (score 0):

check this link: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html
use "^" if it is not starting with 'roll number'

Answer (score 0):

Check that `4` is alone:

```
$ echo "4 24 4aa 44 74 4 9 kk4 09 4 yu4 4 " | tr ' ' '\n' | egrep '\b4\b'
4
4
4
4
```